# Datepicker com array

Tags: datepicker

Estou tentando usar um `datePicker` com input em array, pois são 5 campos de validade, que irei inserir com PHP em um banco Oracle. Usando a opção `class` o `datePicker` é chamado, mas ele somente grava o valor no primeiro input. Ao clicar nos seguintes ele troca no primeiro, sempre. Alguma sugestão?

**DatePicker:**

```
$(function() {
    $(".validade_treinamento").datepicker({
        minDate: 0, //NÃO PERMITIR DATA MENOR QUE A ATUAL
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        dayNames: ['Domingo','Segunda','Terça','Quarta','Quinta','Sexta','Sábado','Domingo'],
        dayNamesMin: ['D','S','T','Q','Q','S','S','D'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sáb','Dom'],
        monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez']
    });
});
```

**Chamada nos inputs:**

```
<input type = "text" id="validade_treinamento[]" name = "validade_treinamento[]"  class="validade_treinamento" placeholder="Clique Aqui" size = 10 maxlength = 10 disabled>
```

**Exemplo**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não entendi isso: `id="validade_treinamento[]"`... já que um id deve ser único na página, não vejo sentido em usar como array.

Comment: @dvd tenho 5 campos iguais, que preciso tratar no PHP como array para futura inserção.

Comment: Sim, a array deve ser usada só no `name`.

Comment: Tens razão, alterei conforme tua resposta e deu certo. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está exatamente aí: usar o mesmo `id` em cada `input`. Isso faz com que o Datepicker aja apenas no primeiro `id` que encontrar, já que um `id` deve ser único na página. Até porque não faz sentido usar array em `id`, se o que importa mesmo é o `name` para o envio dos dados.

A solução é atribuir um `id` próprio para cada `input`. Veja:

```js
$(function() {
    $(".validade_treinamento").datepicker({
        minDate: 0, //NÃO PERMITIR DATA MENOR QUE A ATUAL
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        dayNames: ['Domingo','Segunda','Terça','Quarta','Quinta','Sexta','Sábado','Domingo'],
        dayNamesMin: ['D','S','T','Q','Q','S','S','D'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sáb','Dom'],
        monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez']
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input type = "text" id="validade_treinamento1" name = "validade_treinamento[]"  class="validade_treinamento" placeholder="Clique Aqui" size = 10 maxlength = 10 >
<br>
<input type = "text" id="validade_treinamento2" name = "validade_treinamento[]"  class="validade_treinamento" placeholder="Clique Aqui" size = 10 maxlength = 10 >
<br>
<input type = "text" id="validade_treinamento3" name = "validade_treinamento[]"  class="validade_treinamento" placeholder="Clique Aqui" size = 10 maxlength = 10 >
```